# kvm partial image of disk

Tags: kvm

I am running a linux system as KVM-host and have created a vm running the physical disk of an older PC (using --import). That disk has several partitions with dual-boot of several OS and a scratch partition and some video data ...
What I really want to virtualize is the linux-system on that disk.
I think I understand how to make an image of the entire disk, but what I really need is just the MBR, scratch, and the partitions holding / and /boot.
Is there a way to only 'extract' some partitions to an image for virtualisation?
I am thinking of temporarily copying the partitions of interest to a blank disk, install grub and then virtualize that. But maybe there is  more simple way to achieve what I want?

Kind regards,

Wolfgang

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the disk containing the old PC's system is physically connected to the KVM host, you could do something like this:

1. Use `virsh` or `virt-manager` to create a VM with an appropriately sized disk-image file AND an ISO containing a good rescue CD (I use [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) or [gparted](http://gparted.org/) for things like this.  Any good "live" system should do.  Best **not** to use an installer ISO for any distribution).

   Do **NOT** attach the physical hard disk to the VM yet.
2. Boot the system using the ISO image.  Partition and format the virtual disk (which will probably be `/dev/vda` in the VM) as required.   Mount it as `/target` (and other partitions, if any, under `/target`)
3. On the KVM host, attach the physical disk containing the old system to the VM using the `virsh attach-disk` command.  There's not enough details in your question to give you even an approximate command-line but run `virsh help attach-disk` for a summary of the options.  It will end up being something like:

   `virsh attach-disk vmname /dev/sdX /dev/vdb --targetbus sata`

   where `/dev/sdX` is the physical disk, `/dev/vdb` is the device as it will be seen by the VM, and the target bus will be sata or scsi or even virtio.
4. Back on the VM, mount the OS partition you want to virtualise as `/source` and any other partitions under that.   Mount them all read-only with `mount -o ro /dev/vdbN /target/XXXXX` for safety against typos/mistakes.
5. `rsync -a /source/ /target` (the trailing `/` on `/source/` is important)
6. `umount` everything under `/source`.   you shouldn't need it any longer.
7. `for i in proc dev sys dev/pts ; do mount -o bind /$i /target/$i done`

   This ensures that all the system pseudo-filesystems that `grub-install` and other tools (e.g. `lsblk` or `blkid`) need are bind-mounted and visible inside the `chroot` we're about to enter in the next step.
8. `chroot /target`
9. edit `/etc/fstab` to adjust the mount entries to use the new block device names (or labels, or UUIDs).

   You may want to change other things here like network configuration, or you may want to leave that stuff for later when the basic system is running.   I'd advise taking a copy of any major changes you make, just in case things don't go smoothly the first time and you you have to try again.  Alternatively, just make a note of what you changed so you know what needs to be done if you have to start over.
10. `grub-install /dev/vda`
11. `exit`      # leave the chroot and return you to the shell on the rescue CD image.
12. `for i in proc dev/pts dev proc sys; do umount /target/$i ; done`
13. `umount` everything under `/target`
14. On the KVM host, detach the extra disk with `virsh detach-disk`.

You should now be able to reboot the VM. You may need to tell it to boot from the hard-disk instead of the ISO image virtual "CD-ROM".

Comment: BTW, you can run step 14. immediately after step 6. if you want.  it makes no significant difference.

Comment: Thanks for the detail advise! As far as I see the basic concept is to copy the partitions of interest into an empty image using rsync and then making that 'bootable' with chroot and grub. I will give it a try